# axios delete method not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

i have tried to perform `axios.delete` operation in react, unfortunately it is `not working`, please help me to solve this issue,

```
export function DeletePatient(token,deletePatient) {
  return axios.delete('/patient/billing_delete',deletePatient, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'token': token
    }
  })
    .then(res => { console.log(token); return res.data })
    .catch(err => { console.log(err); return err })
}
```

from my `API response`, i understood that my `token` is passed to `backend`, so i think i should change the structure of this code, please help me

Comment: Where's the React part?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the configuration object should come as second argument:

```
return axios.delete('/patient/billing_delete', {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'token': token
  },
  data: deletePatient
})
```

Comment: What if I wanted to send a delete request passing the id?

Comment: @YuriCardoso Concatenate the id to the url

Comment: How do you set the token variable in this example only for the delete request, not like a global instance ?